# Propel ORM: select criteria with "not in" condition

Tags: mysql, orm, symfony-1.4, propel

How can i build a propel criteria for this type of query:

```
SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE id not in (SELECT id FROM Table2 WHERE field1 = 2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution, it's possible by using `Criteria::CUSTOM`, for example:

```
public static function getElementsWithNotIn(){
    $c = new Criteria();
    $c->add(Table1Peer::ID, Table1Peer::ID . ' NOT IN (SELECT '. Table2Peer::ID .' FROM '. Table2Peer::TABLE_NAME .')', Criteria::CUSTOM);
    return Table1Peer::doSelect($c);
}
```